# Are there Hefeweizen beers with coriander?

Tags: ingredients, hefeweizen

White beer ("[witbier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_beer#Witbier)" in Dutch) is a typical Dutch/Belgian thing, from research I found that it's wheat bear with flavours. This question is about the coriander flavour used in those beers.

The question is about the wheat bear siblings of white beer: Hefeweizen. Are there any hefeweizen that also are coriander-flavoured? To add a more subjective bonus question: are any of those commercially available?

I've tried [Googling](https://www.google.nl/search?q=hefeweizen%20coriander), this mainly seems to lead to brewing recipes or extremely localized experiments. I've *assumed* (perhaps incorrectly) most if not all German candidates would be bound by the [Reinheitsgebot](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/431/412) and as such will not contain coriander. Finally, I've checked some Dutch beers (e.g. "Grolsch Weizen") marketed as "weizen" and the listed ingredients, but so far no dice.

To reiterate the question: **are there any hefeweizen beers with coriander commercially available?**

Comment: I ran a search over on [RateBeer.com](http://www.ratebeer.com/search.php) for 'coriander' and got quite a few results. Unfortunately, hefeweizen doesn't show up as a searchable style on their advanced search, but you can probably scan the list of coriander beers quickly.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Hey, that's interesting. I can search for "German Hefeweizen" as a type (the "Beer Style" dropdown), but do not see where I can enter the term "coriander"? Is there any textbox where I can enter a term/tag?

Comment: I just put it in as part of the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you won't find coriander or other spices added to hefeweizen beers, due to the traditional [beer purity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinheitsgebot).  However, one famous exception is Gose: http://www.germanbeerguide.co.uk/gose.html

Comment: Excellent answer. This both confirms my general thoughts and mentions an exception directly answering my bottom line question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether by Hefeweizen, you mean German white beer? or any white beer?

I am no beer expert, but in Belgium, the famous Hoegaarden does use coriander as a spice for the beer, it gives that imitation-hoppy flavor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoegaarden_Brewery